# Planning to get started code coverage tool

Tags: java, code-coverage

Looking for books or other references that discuss actually to write a code coverage tool in Java; some of the various techniques or tricks - source vs. byte code instrumentation. This is for a scripting language that generates java byte code under the hood.

Any Help would appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the paper "Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy" at http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf